# Как запустить spring в тесте?

Tags: java, spring

@Autowired не может найти подходящий бин, подскажите что требуется добавить

```
@Repository
public interface JsonRepository extends MongoRepository<JSONObject, String> {

}
```

//

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class Test{

   @Autowired
    private JsonRepository repository;


    private final static String JSON_DATA =
            "{"
                    + "      \"id\": \"1\","
                    + "      \"name\": \"Julie Sherman\","
                    + "      \"gender\" : \"female\""

                    + "}";



    @org.junit.Test
    public void  testShouldSaveJSON(){
        repository.deleteAll();

        JSONObject json = null;
        try {
            json = new JSONObject(JSON_DATA);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        repository.save(json);

        for (JSONObject jsonObject : repository.findAll()) {
            try {
                System.out.println(jsonObject.getInt("id"));
                System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("gender"));
                System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("name"));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Вы не указали спрингу где лежит конфигурация контекста. Не помню сейчас какая аннотация указывает на конфигурационные классы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно добавить аннотацию

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = Application.class)
```

где Application.class - имя вашего главного класса у которого стоит @SpringBootApplication